# oauth2 DELETE request, forbidden

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm sending a DELETE server method to an API protected by Oauth2, however, I get the following message.

```
 "error_description": "When putting the token in the body, the method must be POST or PUT"
```

I've been looking documentation regarding to this issue, and I cannot find a way to send other methods than post and put when including the access token to validate the permisions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't the error message clear enough? Put the token in the header.

Comment: no it's no, probably I wouldnt be asking if so. Thanks for answer anyhow. @marekful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire security of OAuth2 is based on the SSL/TLS. Access Tokens are usually passed to the server in the header like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer ee000c4eb0610ed1ed3115571133fcead52b2233
```

In requests like GET and DELETE the access token **must** be passed in the header. For POST and PUT requests it is *okay* to send it in the body, but sending it in the header is recommended.

Comment: for completeness: the server may also support receiving the token as part of the query parameters for all types of requests; see: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-2.3 but it is not recommended

Comment: AUTHORIZATION change to Authorization, it is not working for me with uppercase letters.